# How to use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to prove this inequality?

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, hilbert-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $(E,\langle\, ,\,\rangle)$ a $\mathbb{K}$-prehilbertian space. Let $(e_k)_{1\le k \le n}$, $n$ non-negative vectors of $E$ and $\lambda_1, ... , \lambda_n \in \mathbb{K}$.

Then I want to prove $\Vert \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} \lambda_k e_k \Vert^2 \le \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \vert \lambda_i\vert^2 \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}\vert\langle\,e_i,e_k\,\rangle  \vert$.

I start using the fact that we have :

$\Vert \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} \lambda_k e_k \Vert^2 = \langle\,\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}\lambda_k e_k \,\ \sum \limits_{i=1}^n \lambda_i e_i\,\rangle   = \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} \sum \limits_{i=1}^n \lambda_k \bar{\lambda_i} \langle\,e_k , e_i\,\rangle  = \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} \vert \lambda_k \vert^2 \Vert e_k \Vert^2 + 2\sum \limits_{1\le k < i\le n}\Re(\lambda_k \bar{\lambda_i} \langle\,e_k , e_i\,\rangle )$

$\le \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} \vert \lambda_k \vert^2 \Vert e_k \Vert^2 + 2 \sum \limits_{1\le k < i\le n}\vert \lambda_k \bar{\lambda_i}\vert \vert \langle\,e_k , e_i\,\rangle \vert$.

Then how to continue ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3):

use the fact

$$|\lambda_i \overline{\lambda_j}|\leq \frac{|\lambda_i |^2 +|\lambda_j |^2 }{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

You wrote
$$\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} \sum \limits_{i=1}^n \lambda_k \bar{\lambda_i} \langle\,e_k , e_i\,\rangle  = \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} \vert \lambda_k \vert^2 \Vert e_k \Vert^2 + 2\sum \limits_{1\le k < i\le n}\color{red}{\lambda_k \bar{\lambda_i} \Re(\langle\,e_k , e_i\,\rangle )}.$$
This does not seem right. It should be
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k,i}\lambda_k\overline{\lambda_i}\langle e_k,e_i\rangle
&=\sum_k|\lambda_k|^2\|e_k\|^2
+\sum_{k<i}\lambda_k\overline{\lambda_i}\langle e_k,e_i\rangle
+\sum_{k>i}\lambda_k\overline{\lambda_i}\langle e_k,e_i\rangle\\
&=\sum_k|\lambda_k|^2\|e_k\|^2
+\sum_{k<i}\lambda_k\overline{\lambda_i}\langle e_k,e_i\rangle
+\sum_{k<i}\lambda_i\overline{\lambda_k}\langle e_i,e_k\rangle\\
&=\sum_k|\lambda_k|^2\|e_k\|^2
+2\sum_{k<i}\color{red}{\Re\left(\lambda_k\overline{\lambda_i}\langle e_k,e_i\rangle\right)}.\\
\end{aligned}
Anyway, let $r_{ki}=|\langle e_k,e_i\rangle|$ and let $\langle e_k,e_i\rangle=r_{ki}\omega_{ki}$, where $|\omega_{ki}|=1$. Then
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{i=1}^n \left( |\lambda_i|^2
\sum_{k=1}^n |\langle e_i,e_k\rangle|\right)
-\left\| \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k e_k \right\|^2\\
&=\sum_{k<i} \left(|\lambda_k|^2+|\lambda_i|^2
-\lambda_k\overline{\lambda}_i\omega_{ki}
-\overline{\lambda}_k\lambda_i\overline{\omega_{ki}}
\right)r_{ki}\\
&=\sum_{k<i} \left|\lambda_k\omega_{ki}-\lambda_i\right|^2r_{ki}\\
&\ge0.
\end{aligned}

Comment: Thank you for checking the formula. Why do you have $\langle e_k, e_i \rangle = r_{ik}\omega_{ik}$ ?  It seems that you have not used Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: @Maman Every complex number $z$ can be written in polar form as $re^{i\theta}$, where $r=|z|\ge0$ and $|e^{i\theta}|=1$. In my answer I simply take $\langle e_k,e_i\rangle$ as $z$, $r_{ki}$ as $r$ and $\omega_{ki}$ as $e^{i\theta}$. And no, I didn't use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality because that isn't necessary.